# SQL Query to return a list of account numbers that have only ordered before (x) date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Apologies in advance if this turns out to be very easy, but I am new to SQL

I need help building a query for a database that contains a list of AccountCodes and OrderDates.  Every order that has ever been made is contained in this database.

I can generate a query that will give me everything ordered before 2015 however it ignores if they have ordered after.  Also this gives me duplicate account codes which is not helpful as I need to use this list to do another function after.

What I am seeking is a query that will give me any account number that their **last** order was before 2015-01-01 without any duplication any account numbers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

I ended up using the incremented search from P Salmon and playing around with it to get exactly what i needed to put into update query,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is:

```
select whatever
from wherever
where some conditions are met
and not exists
(
subquery to identify the records after x date
)
```

The first part is what you say you already have.

**Edit starts here**

The above will satisfy the `only before x date` part of your question.  Regarding duplicate account codes, that may or may not be possible in this query depending on what other fields are needed.  However, there are ways to create a distinct list.  It depends on many things, none of which are included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  AccountCodes,
  OrderDates
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  (OrderDates <= '2015-01-01') AND OrderDates NOT IN(
  SELECT
    AccountCodes,
    OrderDates
  FROM
    'table'
  WHERE
    OrderDates > '2015-01-01'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an auto_increment id in your orders table you can use a sub query to pick only those you are interested in with a max clause

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select aw.salesorderid,aw.customerid, aw.orderdate
    -> from awsalesorderheader aw
    -> where  aw.customerid in (11001,11002,12368);
+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| salesorderid | customerid | orderdate           |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+
|        43767 |      11001 | 2005-07-18 00:00:00 |
|        51493 |      11001 | 2007-07-20 00:00:00 |
|        72773 |      11001 | 2008-06-12 00:00:00 |
|        43736 |      11002 | 2005-07-10 00:00:00 |
|        51238 |      11002 | 2007-07-04 00:00:00 |
|        53237 |      11002 | 2007-08-27 00:00:00 |
|        71664 |      12368 | 2008-05-30 00:00:00 |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select aw.salesorderid,aw.customerid, aw.orderdate
    -> from awsalesorderheader aw
    -> where  salesorderid = (select max(aw1.salesorderid) from awsalesorderheader aw1 where aw1.CustomerID = aw.customerid
    -> and aw1.orderdate < '2008-01-01' and aw.customerid in (11001,11002,12368))
    -> order by aw.customerid;
+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| salesorderid | customerid | orderdate           |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+
|        51493 |      11001 | 2007-07-20 00:00:00 |
|        53237 |      11002 | 2007-08-27 00:00:00 |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.19 sec)
```

If you don't have an auto_increment id then you could substitute id with orderdate in the where and sub query but you may need to add a distinct clause to the select.